# POE Adapter + TP-Link Outdoor CPE blinking light

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, power-supply

I'm trying to set up a wifi network using an outdoor CPE (TP-LINK WA5210G) connected to a POE Adapter (Ubiquiti Switching Mode Power Supply) for an NGO I'm volunteering with. The people claim that the equipment used to work well until the wifi network just "disappeared". At the moment, the PoE adapter and the outdoor CPE simply blink every second or so.

What could be wrong? Search results suggest that the blinking could be a result of overload (the CPE requiring a higher voltage than the adapter can supply), but in that case, I don't see how it could've worked before.

I've tested the cables and used different PoE adapters, with the same result. How do I go about fixing this setup?

Comment: Take the cpe indoors, power it directly with it's own power supply, see if it works. Replace cable between poe and cpe. Be warned ubiquity uses some proprietary poe, that is not real poe.

Comment: Unfortunately, the [CPE in question](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/TL-WA5210G_V1_User_Guide_1910010274.pdf) doesn't seem to support power supply other than through PoE.

Comment: What about it own power injector (as the manual implies)?

Comment: Oh, do try another ethernet cable between cpe and poe injector, if you have one known good handy